# Problem with scanf, C. Floating point exception

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, scanf

i'm learning C.

i'm using ubuntu and have Code::Blocks as IDE
i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rev (int num);

int main (){
    int numb = 0;

    printf("%d\n\n", numb);

    printf("Please enter a number. Enter 9999 to stop\n");
    scanf("%d", &numb);
    printf("there?");
    printf("%d\n", numb);

    while (numb != 9999){
        printf("The reversed number is %d\n", rev(numb));
        printf("Please enter a number. Enter 9999 to stop\n");
        scanf("%d", &numb);
    } /* end of while */

}

int rev (int num){
    printf("here?");
    int total = 0;
    long max = 10;
    long max_const = 10;

    printf("here");

    for (max; max < num; max *= 10);

    printf("%ld", max);

    max_const = max;

    for (int i = 0; i <= max_const; i *= 10, max /= 10){
        total += num / max * i;
    } /* end for */

    return total;
}
```

I'm doing it in this way cause my book isn't clear...however, the problem is that it raise a Floating Point exception, in scanf...i'm typing normal numbers... the strange thing is that if i type everything but 9999, the program crash. if i type 9999, it prints 'there?' (so scanf it's ok) and stop later, obviously. why?

Thank you.

Comment: So if you type anything other than 9999 it crashes without printing "there"? What do you mean by "crash"? What does it do? Segfault? Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: @Falmarri: Presumably it generates a floating point exception...

Comment: exactly, it generates a floating point exception. If i type 9999, it prints there? and stop. if i type anything else, it raises a Floating Point exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two existing (be sure to return the result in `rev`, and put `\n` on the ends of printfs to be sure they make it through the buffer) answers are good points, but not the thing that's actually triggering your floating point exception. Try running it in a debugger, and you'll see that your algorithm is bad: eventually `max` becomes zero and you divide by it. I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for the reader; the problem isn't anything to do with scanf.

Comment: and what should i use instead of scanf? :) and even if max becomes 0, my func rev is never called...so it would change something?

Comment: @Ant: I didn't say change your usage of scanf. I said that it's not your problem at all. Your `rev` function doesn't work. Try using a debugger, like we've suggested, to help you see why. If you need some proof, change your main to just call `rev(123)` and see what happens.

Comment: ok maybe a get the point. sorry.. i chenge rev so that in 'return 9' and the program works, so it's definitevely a rev problem...sorry ;)

Comment: I originally gave the full answer but I'm with Jefromi.  There's a bug in your rev() function, it doesn't involve scanf().

Answer (score 1):

Your rev function needs to return the reversed number.